# Integrate social media network sharing buttons to Highcharts.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, social-networking, highcharts

I am using Highcharts plugin for my web site. So, I have a requirement for share charts (as an image) with social media networks. Has anyone got a idea about to integrate social media network sharing buttons to Highcharts.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) can help. As with AddThis, you can add socials networking sharing buttons to your site and also view analytics on their site :)

Comment: I tried using sharethis & addthis widgets but none of them showing a highchart as image in share dialog.

Answer (score 0):

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) gives you the piece of code that you need to put on your page. Using that you can easily share with social networking site.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

this plugin also seems promising
 http://plugins.in1.com/share

it's light weight and good looking, also you can provide a url to share or let it share the current page url
here is an example

```
$('#mydiv3').share({
    networks: ['twitter','facebook','tumblr','pinterest','googleplus'],
    orientation: 'vertical',
    urlToShare: 'http://www.in1.com',
    affix: 'right center'
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that, I'll modify answer

Comment: the answer is updated