# Share highcharts to Facebook and Twitter ?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, twitter, highcharts

Hi guys i am working on highcharts and as our current project is going to be facebook and twitter integrated.

is there anything that allows highcharts on a page to be shared on facebook on click of a button

i dont at the moment if there is any but if it is please let me know ?

[image]

Comment: i would probably like the view of highcharts team is this something in coming in future or if it can be done at present ?

Answer (score 0):

I advice to familiar with this solution [Integrate social media network sharing buttons to Highcharts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708855/integrate-social-media-network-sharing-buttons-to-highcharts) but you can also request your suggestion in the uservoice http://highcharts.uservoice.com/ which gathers all propositions.